# How can i change the default Bootstrap button color to my own choice of custom color by using CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
.nav-link {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#about">about</a>
</li>
```

Every other element in the css part is working except the color element. When i inspected the webpage in chrome developer tool, It showed that the css is not overriding the default bootstrap button color (rgba).

Comment: it's working fine, if you mean the hover then you'll have to override the hover also using `:hover`

Answer (score 0):

First add a new class to your element, then over writing bootstrap styles using `important`

```css
.nav-link {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #ededed;
}
.new-class{
/* over write */
color:red !important;
font-size:30px !important;
/* etc */
}
.new-class:hover{
    color:#000 !important;
    
}
.il-style
{
 list-style:none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="nav-item il-style">
  <a class="nav-link new-class" href="#about">about</a>
</li>
```

- Or u can call your `style.css` after **bootstrap style**  without using `important`, but sometime you need to use it.